# How do I handle newlines in shuf, calc etc?

Tags: bash, csv, ubuntu, twitter, newline

I have written a bash script:

`for f in *.csv; do  shuf -n 1000 "$f" > ./1000/"${f%.csv}_1000.csv" ; done`

Which for each .csv files in a directory randomly writes 1000 lines to a new file with the suffix '_1000' in  the directory /1000, i.e.

```
afolder/cat.csv
afolder/dog.csv
```

becomes:

```
afolder/1000/cat_1000.csv
afolder/1000/dog_1000.csv
```

Each record is a tweet. This works fine except when input files have newline characters. For example one of my tweet records has a text field with newline characters:

```
   Hope Abbo gets his Sen in #bcafc trenches with McCall &amp; Black..
    More Warriors The Better 
    #ShoulderToShoulder
```

This is handled correctly in Libroffice Calc file [image]

the three lines are kept together in one record (although this does not appear so in the image because calc has expanded the field).

When I look at the output, shuf has chosen one of the three text lines instead of keeping them together:
[image]

Is there anyway of telling shuf to keep them together?

Comment: Is it acceptable to you if you create a temporary file first which replaced these newlines with some unique string, putting the entire post on the same line?

Comment: `shuf` is not appropriate for this task. You need a CSV parser.

Comment: +1 @RuslanOsmanov - the basic problem statement can easily be achieved with `while IFS=, read tweet; do ... done < file.csv`

Comment: @alok yes that is acceptable. Could you explain to me a little the while IFS=, solution, I am a newbie when it comes to scripting.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov why is it not acceptable? Can shuf not handle csv files? Please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @schoon, _shuf_ operates on lines, while a CSV row may contain multiple lines: `4,"line1\nline2"` (`\n` is the newline character). You really need a CSV parser. As a PHP developer, I would read the file into an array with [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), then [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) it. The same is easily done with Perl's `Text::CSV` module and `shuffle` subroutine from `List::Util` module.

Comment: He probably wants to refer to the fact that a CSV parser reads text files from one comma to the next, while shuf reads them one line at a time. Can you share a part of your CSV, preferably covering all corner scenarios so I can answer with a proper script.

Comment: @alok, still I wouldn't implement the parser in shell. There are many cases such as a comma within the value: `1,"2,3",4` (3 columns), and quotes within the value: `"""1"",2"` (`"1",2`). Of course, it is possible to handle them in pure shell, but I would rather use an existing reliable tool.

Comment: @alok thanks. Sample file [here](http://dropcanvas.com/#P4063W5lrSWNC2).

Comment: @schoon - Sorry, I didn't get to see your sample file and now it has expired. But have you considered the scenarios mentioned by Ruslan as your corner scenarios? Because that could be a serious issue for a simplistic script. You will need a sophisticated CSV parser and if you don't have programming experience, you need to find work-arounds for such scenarios.(Eliminate such cases at the time of creation of the text file)

Comment: Thanks Alok. The text files are already created unfortunately. I'll see if I can get Python to some csv parsing.